# Генерация ключа посредством SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()?

Tags: java, случайные-числа, безопасность, key

Как правильно генерировать секретный ключ с помощью SecureRandom.**getInstanceStrong()**?

Через этот код я получаю массив байт. Есть ли еще способы сгенерировать ключ заданной длины (**256** бит, к примеру), заданного типа данных (**int, String**) и заданного формата (**hex**, bin, dec)?

```
package com.company;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class KeyGen {

    public void generate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        byte[] values = new byte[32]; // 256 bit
        random.nextBytes(values);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : values) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        System.out.print("Key: ");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

На выходе получим что-то вроде этого:

`Key: 8fcea84897f48f575c22441ece4e7ddb43ac08cd2c1a83fca46c080768468059`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String createHash(final char[] password)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    final byte[] salt = new byte[256];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    final byte[] hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, 1000, 256);
    return "sha1:" + 1000 + ':' + toBase64(salt) + ':' + toBase64(hash);
}

private static byte[] pbkdf2(final char[] password, final byte[] salt, final int iterations, final int bytes)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    final KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
    final SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.